# C# Bitmap.Save Method , JPEG

Tags: c#, .net, image, jpeg

Im creating a new Bitmap object as below,

```
var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\file.jpg");
```

I will be doing several modifications in pixel levels in the spatial domain and if save this object again as below.

```
 image.Save(@"D:\final.jpg", ImageFormat.bitmap);
```

1. Is this final image is a really a jpg or a bitmap ? ,

Using this functional is there a way we can save a jpg lossless ?

Comment: What do you mean buy this - "save a jpg looseness"?

Comment: Maybe, it means lossless.

Answer (score 6):

```
image.Save(@"D:\final.jpg", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

will save a bitmap image in spite of the extension

Jpg is a lossy compression method, if you want loseless you can use either Bmp or Png

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap` class is always in a 'raw' format. So what happens in your code is:

1. Read from a JPEG file (lossy format) into a Bitmap class (raw lossless format).
2. Save the contents of the Bitmap class into another file (BMP lossless format).

The contents of the Bitmap class after that is *still* in raw lossless format so that you can continue to manipulate it, or save it to file in yet another format (lossless or lossy).

Note: The 'raw' format I mentioned above is not the same format as some .raw files that you sometimes encounter in music editing programs. By 'raw' format I just mean some temporary arbitrary format that `Bitmap` uses to store the image data in itself (possibly in `byte[]`).